# index out of bounds trying to enable minimizing via taskbar icon

Tags: java, javafx

```
long lhwnd = com.sun.glass.ui.Window.getWindows().get(0).getNativeWindow();
Pointer lpVoid = new Pointer(lhwnd);
HWND hwnd = new HWND(lpVoid);
final User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
int oldStyle = user32.GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
int newStyle = oldStyle | 0x00020000;//WS_MINIMIZEBOX
user32.SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, newStyle);
```

I'm getting an index out of bounds (index 0 size 0) for

```
    long lhwnd = com.sun.glass.ui.Window.getWindows().get(0).getNativeWindow();
```

Any idea's why? I'm trying to enable the minimizing fuction of the taskbar icon of my Javafx application.

Comment: Well, because `getWindows` doesnt return any windows, then index of 0 is out of bound for an empty array. The real question is why isnt `getWindows` returning any windows.

Comment: Ye that's what I meant obviously. Any idea?

Comment: From the Javadoc is seems that the Windows are not yet visible when the `getWindows()` is called, as it only returns visible windows.

Comment: I doubt it. From clicking around it seems like it would have to be called after `stage.show()` in your application. Im not sure where its called from now, but that seems to be what populates the list that you are trying to get.

Comment: Damn it was that easy.. If you answer it i'll mark it so other people won't have to go through this.. Thank you man :) P.S. even now I know the problem I don't get it as it shouldn't have anything to do with the application itself to be shown.. But whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when `Window.getWindows()` is called, it checks for **visible** windows. You must be calling it before a `stage.show()`.

Move the call to after a `stage.show()` and you should be getting a populated array now.